# Controlling the browser URL during redirect via Struts

Tags: java, redirect, struts

Forgive me if the information I provide is limited, but I am restricted in what I can provide.

We have a login process that invokes a struts action.  This action, in combination with the http server and redirects sends the user to a specific JSP via a sort of "dummy" action.  The problem is this page/action needs to be "set up" in order to function properly.  Customers want to bookmark the login page but when they do so, and then invoke the bookmark, it fails because it has not been set up properly.

My question is this:  Is there a way to control the URL so that they bookmark the action that sets up this action/page, instead?

Thank you.

[edit]

More information:

j_security uses protected pages to trigger login. When the login is triggered we intercept via urlrewrite for context switching... but the final result is a page that is not protected (the login page) and people are bookmarking that page. Unfortunately if you go directly to that page the login process fails because it requires that "set up" of the protected page.

Is there a way to mask the URL even once forwarded to reflect the protected page that triggers the login? A rewrite statement of some sort?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what "set up" means. If it's not "set up" why don't you just redirect to the page where it can be "set up."?

Comment: I know, I am sorry!!  Do you mean if they hit the page directly, why not redirect to the other action?  If so, I don't believe I can do that without causing a loop of some sort.

Comment: Presumably they would submit some form variables to get to the login page (the "set up"), if those don't exist send them back.